# background service is used to scan Beacon?

Tags: android, ibeacon, beacon

I can scan the Beacon in foreground using `beaconManager.startScan();` so it is giving the beacons info available in the area.
same code I am using in service to scan the beacon and there also I am getting the beacon info.
But for scanning the beacon in background, I have to start the service.So is it the right practice to scan beacon using service.?

Comment: What beacon scanning library are you using?

Comment: I am using UFOBeacons [link](https://www.ufobeacon.com/developer/ufobeaconsdk.html)

Comment: See the answer from @heypiotr for why you don't want to use a background service.  If you don't want to roll your own foreground service, you might consider using a the open source [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/), which has built-in support for background scanning using either a JobScheduler or a foreground service. It will set this up automatically depending on the version of Android upon which your app is running.

Comment: Seems useful..i would like to try this one...Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The topic of doing Bluetooth scanning in the background on Android is quite… interesting/complicated these days…

1. Using a background service isn't really a good option anymore. Starting with API 26 (Android 8.0), background services only continue running for a few more minutes once the user leaves the app.

   (Arguably, it's not even a good option on older Androids. At Estimote, we found that some big-name Android smartphone manufacturers include their own power-management "optimizations" in their customized versions of Android, that tend to kill background services.)
2. You can use a *foreground* service, which has no limitations, but requires you to show a notification to inform the user that your app is still doing some work.
3. Finally, the good news is, in Android 8.0 there's a new API for Bluetooth scanning, where the BLE scan results get delivered via a `PendingIntent` rather than a standard callback. This will work even if the app got suspended/terminated in the meantime.

   [`startScan(List<ScanFilter> f, ScanSettings s, PendingIntent i)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html#startScan(java.util.List<android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter>,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

   The bad news is of course, since this is API 26 (Android 8.0) and higher, you can't really rely on it much yet, as the Android 8 adoption is still very low. The future for background BLE scanning on Android looks bright, it's just not quite here yet.

--

Naturally, if you're using a ready-made scanning lib, it's best to consult with its authors about its background capabilities and how to use them.

The https://github.com/ufobeacons/Android-SDK lib seems (at a first glance at least) not to have any background support of its own, so you're probably best off just wrapping it in a foreground service.

Comment: Great answer.  It's worth noting that if you don't want a constant user-visible notification from a foreground service,  an alternative on Android 8+ is the JobScheduler.  But this is limited to scheduling scans every ~15 minutes.